# How to find uncertainty of fitting with multi parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to find the uncertainty, of a function that involves two parameters, by finding working with reduced chi_squared, however, I don't know how to do it

Comment: what have you tried? what functions did you used?

Comment: I have found reduced chi squared, so I know that the uncertainty will be the width of the axes however I am not sure how to find it, can you give me extra hint

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.